# Why does chrome make HTML cache in download directory?

Tags: html, google-chrome, caching, browser, browser-cache

When I open the same .html file that exists in local with Chrome multiple times,
Chrome makes a html cache folder in the download directory, name like `file%3A`

And then I refresh a page after edit that file, still Chrome show me a cached file, not a edited

Even the hard reload does not work after cache folder has been created

Why does chrome doing this..

Only way to get edited file is delete the cache folder

Is there anyway to prevent the creation of cache folder by Chrome?